# Why is Browserify making my compiled Javascript file huge in file size?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, browserify

I'm using Browserify with Gulp to compile some ES6 -> ES5 and doing basic concatenation for my files. Right now all my project has is different Javascript files that allow a user to upload files to a Google Cloud bucket.

When I test some things out by only compiling one of my files, Browserify, for some reason, compiles my Javascript into a huge file that is over 2MB. After further inspection, it seems that Browserify is taking its dependencies and adding it to my file which seems unnecessary.

**The main problem is that Browserify is including its own `node_modules` in my outputted Javascript.**

Below are some file setup examples with the output I'm receiving.

**Test Javascript File** (text.js)

This is a simple file that uses an npm package to send a text when something has been uploaded and exports the needed function.

```
'use strict'
function sendText(name) {
  // Twilio Credentials
  var accountSid = '<SID NUMBER>';
  var authToken = '<AUTH NUMBER>';

  //require the Twilio module and create a REST client
  var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

  client.messages.create({
   to: '<TO NUMBER>',
   from: '<FROM NUMBER>',
   body: 'Body text here',
  }, function(err, message) {
   console.log(message.sid);
  });
}

module.exports = {
  sendText: sendText
}
```

I'm referring `text.js` in an `index.js` file that will include all the scripts and serve as an entry file for Browserify.

**index.js**

```
import sendText from './uploads/text.js';
```

**Browserify Task**

```
import gulp         from 'gulp';
import gulpif       from 'gulp-if';
import gutil        from 'gulp-util';
import source       from 'vinyl-source-stream';
import streamify    from 'gulp-streamify';
import sourcemaps   from 'gulp-sourcemaps';
import rename       from 'gulp-rename';
import watchify     from 'watchify';
import browserify   from 'browserify';
import babelify     from 'babelify';
import uglify       from 'gulp-uglify';
import browserSync  from 'browser-sync';
import debowerify   from 'debowerify';
import handleErrors from '../util/handle-errors';
import config       from '../config';


function buildScript(file, watch) {

  // Takes a our specified index.js file as the entry point for compiling

  let bundler = browserify({
    entries: ['./src/assets/js/' + file],
    debug: false,
    cache: {},
    packageCache: {},
    fullPaths: global.isProd ? false : true
  });

  // Watch for changes in javascript

  if ( watch ) {
    bundler = watchify(bundler);
    bundler.on('update', rebundle);
  }

  // ES5 -> ES6

  bundler.transform(babelify);
  bundler.transform(debowerify);

  // Rebundle any changes appllied

  function rebundle() {
    const stream = bundler.bundle();

    gutil.log('Rebundle...');

    // Check for errors in stream + listen for production environment

    return stream.on('error', handleErrors)
    .pipe(source(file))
    .pipe(gulpif(global.isProd, streamify(uglify())))
    .pipe(streamify(rename({
      basename: 'main'
    })))
    .pipe(gulpif(!global.isProd, sourcemaps.write('./')))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest.js))
    .pipe(gulpif(browserSync.active, browserSync.reload({ stream: true, once: true })));
  }

  return rebundle();

}

gulp.task('browserify', function() {

  // Only run watchify if NOT production
  return buildScript('index.js', !global.isProd);

});
```

Pasting the output code was too large even for paste bin, so I'm not sure what information from that could be helpful, but I can provide anything that is needed.

Comment: The *whole point* of browserify (or webpack) is to bundle your code with dependencies. If you're worried about file size, consider using fewer dependencies.

Comment: @ssube that's not my problem though. I've seen projects with way more dependencies than what I'm using and have small file sizes. And as I mentioned, all of the dependencies that seem to be included into the output file are all coming from Browserify.

Comment: Did you actually look through the compiled code to see what it is including? are you sure it isn't all twilio, it's dependencies, and it's dependencies' dependencies?

Comment: @KevinB 100% checked. Here's a sample of the [output](http://pastebin.com/pEiYD1fw) Notice how most of the modules are from Browserify.

Comment: yeah, a lot of those are polyfilling built-in node modules likely being used by twilio, no? said modules don't exist in the browser, so browserify has to include them.

Comment: @KevinB so is there no work around to my problem?

Comment: Are you browserifying this to run on a browser? if not, then the solution is to... not use browserify, it's the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @KevinB Yes, I am wanting to run this all in the browser.

Comment: then no, you need all of that extra junk for it to work properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/119046/discussion-between-privateer35-and-kevin-b).